# Como mando datos de una ventana modal con ajax y php a mysql?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo una ventana modal que manda datos a una tabla en mysql llamada (trabajos) que tiene tres campos (Id_trabajo, Nombre_Trabajo y Costo) y asi mismo muestra esos datos en la tabla en html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que al mandar los datos, me sale un mensaje de que ha sido correctamente, pero me lo manda a otra pagina y me tengo que regresar a la pag anterior y recargar para que se actualize, quiero que ese mensaje me salga dentro de mi ventana modal, o en mi pagina donde tengo mi tabla (consulta_lista.php), me dijieron que utilizara ajax, pero no se como se hace, tengo lo siguiente en mi archivo (agregar_modal.php), para que se ejecute tengo que tener alguna librería?no se a lo mejor jquery o algo? y si esta bien que coloque mi script en ese archivo? o lo puedo colocar donde tengo mi tabla?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#guardar').click(function(){
       var parametros = {
            "nombre" : $("#txt_nombre").val(),
            "costo" : $("#txt_costo").val()
      }
      $.ajax({
              data : parametros,
              url : "agregarModal_validacion.php"
              type : "post"
              success : function(response){
                     
              }
       })
});
</script>


<!-- Modal-->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
      </div> 
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control " type="text" id="txt_costo" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es correcto de esta manera? o como mas lo puedo hacer? y es que me dijieron que en mi php cambie la respuesta y la deje con json, pero que es eso? como lo hago?
Ojala me puedan ayuda por favor, les dejo mi codigo de mi php

```html
<?php

 ?>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minium-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<?
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "registros");
if($conexion)
{
//Variables
  $Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['nombre'];
  $Costo=$_POST['costo'];

//realiza la consulta
  $consulta= "INSERT INTO trabajos (Nombre_Trabajo, Costo) values ('$Nombre_Trabajo','$Costo')";
  
  //para ejecutar consulta
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta);
 
  if ($resultado) 
  { 
    $messages[]  = "Los datos han sido agregados correctamente";
  }
    
  else 
  {
    $errors[]= "No se puedo realizar la accion";
  } 
      
if (isset($errors)){
      
      ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="consulta_lista.php">&times;</button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> 
          <?php
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error;
              }
            ?>
      </div>
      <?php
      }

if (isset($messages)){
        
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="myModal1">&times;</button>
            <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
            <?php
              foreach ($messages as $message) {
                  echo $message;
                }
              ?>
        </div>
        <?php
      }

  

}
  else{ 
        echo ""; 
      }
        mysqli_close($conexion);   
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
               data : parametros,
               url : "agregarModal_validacion.php"
               type : "post"
               success : function(response){
                   //Recibes la respuesta y la muestras en un div
                   var mensaje = response.message;
               }
    })
```

En la success recibes la respuesta de parte del servidor a tu petición ajax, aquí en la variable response tienes la respuesta, que en tu caso será error o Los datos han sido agregados correctamente. Ahora en la parte del servidor guardas esos mensajes en una variable y codificarlo en formato JSON:

```
$jsondata['success'] = true; //En caso de exito
$jsondata['message'] = 'Hola! El valor recibido es correcto.'; // el mensaje
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```

Comment: lo de la parte de jsondata lo pongo en mi archivo  php asi nada mas? o tengo que agregarle otra cosa? es que no me hace nada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices las ventajas de jquery para formularios y te ahorrarás muchos problemas...

La nueva versión de jQuery no acepta las funciones `.click()` por lo que puedes sustituirlo por `$(".clase/#id").on("click", function() {`

En este caso, te haré un ejemplo de lo que haría yo...

```
<!-- Modal-->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
      </div> 

        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <form action="#" class="modalForm">

          <!--Contenido del modal-->
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xm-6">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xm-6">
              <input class="form-control " type="text" id="txt_costo" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo" required="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
          <!--Final del modal-->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
          </div>

       </form>
       <!-- FORMULARIO - END -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Luego en el código javascript lo cambiaría de esta manera...

```
$("#myModal1").on("submit", ".modalForm", function(){
    var parametros= {
        "txt_nombre" : $("input#txt_nombre").val(),
        "txt_costo" : $("input#txt_nombre").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "agregarModal_validacion.php",
        data: params,
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function() {
        }
    })
    return false; // Esto para evitar que envíe el formulario.
})
```

Espero que con este código hayas aprendido algo nuevo y te adaptes a la nueva versión de jQuery :)

Comment: En el código javascript que te he añadido, fíjate que la función inicial `$("#myModal1").on("submit", ".modalForm", function(){` pongo primero el modal, y luego la clase del formulario.

Comment: Eso es porque sólo quiero hacerlo en esa clase que se encuentra dentro de ese bloque. Esto te ayudara mucho, si quieres cargar dentro del modal, diferentes contenidos con un unico codigo del modal. ( `submit` es para cuando envías el formulario)